# Distributed data parallel for model where the batch size is changing

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to implement FNO-MiONet architecture from this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.04778). In this architecture, the batch size changes during the forward pass. Below is the code for the network till branch-truck operation.

```
def forward(self, xfield, xscalars, xtime):
        batchsize_x = xfield.shape[0]
        size_x, size_y = xfield.shape[1], xfield.shape[2]
        size_t = xtime.shape[-1]
        
        # ==================================== MIOnet ====================================
        x_b1 = self.fc_b1(xfield) #[bs, nz, nx, width]
        x_b2 = self.fc_b2(xscalars) #[bs, width]
        x_branch = x_b1 + x_b2[:,None,None,:] #[bs, nz, nx, width]
        
        x_trunk = self.fc_t1(xtime) #[nt, width]
        x_branch = x_branch.unsqueeze(1)
        x_branch = x_branch.repeat(1, size_t, 1, 1, 1) #[bs, nt, nz, nx, width]

        # Reshape trunk output to match the dimensions of the branch output
        x_trunk = x_trunk.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(-2).unsqueeze(-2) #[1, nt, 1, 1, width]
        
        # multiply branch and trunk output
        x = x_branch * x_trunk
        
        x = x.reshape((batchsize_x*size_t, size_x, size_y, -1))
        # ==================================== Fourier layers====================================
        
        x = x.reshape((batchsize_x, size_t, size_x, size_y, -1))
        return x
```

The model works with a single GPU. However, I cannot use this model with the DataParallel option in PyTorch. If I use 4 GPUs with a batch size of four, the model's output with the DataParallel option is just one sample and not 4.

```
for x, s, y in train_loader:
    x, s, y = x.to(device), s.to(device), y.to(device)
    t = train_t.to(device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    pred = ddp_model(x, s, t)
```

When I tried to do some testing for my code with 4 GPUs and 4 batchsize for the train_loader, I got only 1 sample for the pred variable.